# How To Fix a div height reset error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

After About a minute, the height will be set to only the top bar showing in the below snippet, can someone help me fix this? Just try to run the script and see that it'll eventually show only the top bar. Any and all help is appreciated! This error happened after the implementation of a custom scroll bar, if that helps anyone solve my problum!

## I have also created this  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/db20w5be/1/)

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
 
 <style>
  html, body{ height: 100%; }
 </style>
 
</head>

<body class="full-page">
 <header>

  <hr />
 </header>
 
 <div id="demo">
  <section id="examples">
   
   <div class="content mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="minimal">

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .navbar-form {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .nav {
  float: right !important;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .nav .dropdown span.fa,
.wrap .nav-bar .nav .dropdown span.caret {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .nav .dropdown-menu {
  background: #222;
  left: auto;
  width: 200px;
  right: 0;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
.wrap .nav-bar .nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background: #3355ff;
}
.wrap .side-menu-link {
  left: 21em;
}
.wrap .burger {
  position: relative;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 500000;
}
.wrap .burger .burger_inside {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 2.5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.wrap .burger #bgrOne {
  top: 0;
}
.wrap .burger #bgrTwo {
  top: 10px;
}
.wrap .burger #bgrThree {
  top: 20px;
}
.wrap #side-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #404040;
  width: 22em;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  height: 900px;
}
.wrap .content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.wrap .content .top-bar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.wrap .content .content-inner {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap ul.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
.wrap ul.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  color: #9D9D9D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #303030;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.wrap ul.accordion li:not(open) last-child .link {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.wrap ul.accordion li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.wrap ul.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 12px;
  left: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.wrap ul.accordion li.open .link {
  color: #FFB266;
}
.wrap ul.accordion li.open i {
  color: #FFB266;
}
.wrap ul.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.wrap ul.accordion ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap ul.accordion ul.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
  list-style: none;
}
.wrap ul.accordion ul.submenu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.wrap ul.accordion ul.submenu li a:hover {
  background: rgba(240, 128, 128, 0.8);
  color: #ffb266;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrap .nav-bar .navbar-brand {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .wrap .side-menu-link {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .wrap #side-menu #qform {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .wrap .content {
    left: 0;
  }
  .wrap.active .content {
    left: 21em;
  }
  .wrap.active .content #bgrOne {
    top: 10px;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  .wrap.active .content #bgrTwo {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .wrap.active .content #bgrThree {
    top: 10px;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .side-menu-link {
    display: none;
  }
  .wrap {
    position: relative;
  }
  .wrap .content {
    left: 21em;
     right: 0;
  }
}

    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert = function(){};
        var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
        function changeCSS(css){
            if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
            else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
          window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'https://bootsnipp.com');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- <body style="visibility: hidden !important;">
 <div id="babasbmsgx" style="visibility: visible !important;">Please disable your adblock and script blockers to view this page</div>-->

 <div class="wrap">
  <nav class="nav-bar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div id ="top-menu" class="container-fluid active">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AntiMalwareProgram</a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">        
   
              <form id="qform" class="navbar-form pull-left" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search" role="search">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"
  type="submit" placeholder="Search all of Google!" />                        
               </form>

              <li class="dropdown movable">
                   <img id="fa fa-4x fa-child" src="" >

                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span><span class="fa fa-4x fa-child"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="https://www.authpro.com/auth/antimalwareprogram/?action=edit "><span class="fa fa-user"></span>Edit Profile</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.authpro.com/auth/antimalwareprogram/?action=del "><span class="fa fa-gear"></span>Cancel Account</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.authpro.com/auth/antimalwareprogram/?action=logout
"><span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>Log Out</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              
          </ul>
      </div>      
  </nav>
  <aside id="side-menu" class="aside" role="navigation">            
        <ul class="nav nav-list accordion">                    
          <li class="nav-header">
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>Current pages<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">About Current Pages(You Are Here)</a></li>  
              <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/joomla/index.php">Joomla Pages</a></li> 
     <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/wordpress/">Blogs</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:welcome">Community Editable Wiki</a></li>


     
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-header">
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-users"></i>Users<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="https://www.authpro.com/auth/antimalwareprogram/?action=edit">Edit Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.authpro.com/auth/antimalwareprogram/?action=del">Cancel Account</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-header">
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>Forms<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Support_Tickets=true&active=true">Submit a support ticket</a></li>  
              <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Feedback_Survey">Feedback Survey</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Vote_For_Content">Vote For Content</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Contact_Us">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>  
          
           <li class="nav-header">
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-map-marker"></i>Go Back/Forward Buttons<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a onclick="goBack()">Go Back</a></li>  
    <li><a onclick="goForward()">Go Forward</a></li>  




            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-header">
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-file-image-o"></i>Other<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/What's_New.php">What's New?</a></li> 
     <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/copyright_notice.php">&copy; 2016-<?php echo date("Y");?></a></li>
              <li><a href="/Mailing_List">Our Mailing List</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">Comming Soon</a></li>          
              <li><a href="#">Comming Soon</a></li>


            </ul>
          </li>
     <li class="nav-header">
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-file-image-o"></i>AntiMalwareProgram!<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="/results.html">Results</a></li> 
              <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>          
              <li><a href="/test-malware.html">Malware Test</a></li>


            </ul>
          </li>
            <img id="myImg" src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/RapidSSL_SEAL-90x50.gif" alt="Rapid SSL Image" width="100%" height="100">

      </ul>
  </aside>

  <!--Body content-->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top-bar">       
      <a href="#menu" class="side-menu-link burger"> 
        <span class='burger_inside' id='bgrOne'></span>
        <span class='burger_inside' id='bgrTwo'></span>
        <span class='burger_inside' id='bgrThree'></span>
      </a>      
    </div>
    <section class="content-inner">
   <script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
   <script>
function goForward() {
    window.history.forward();
}
</script>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>

  
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-7824087727433149",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
  
  
  <!-- Google Code for antimalwareprogram.co Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 934367017;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "PWD9CPGJ13MQqZ7FvQM";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/934367017/?label=PWD9CPGJ13MQqZ7FvQM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action = "first">First thing</li>
  <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
  <style>
 .custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
  </style>
  <script>
 
<!-- 
This code is developed by Anand Roshan for www.voidtricks.com  tutorial
Tutorial URI : http://www.voidtricks.com/custom-right-click-context-menu/
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  .menu{
   width: 100px;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 999999;
   display: none;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #713C3C;
  }
  .menu ul{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
  }
  .menu ul a{
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .menu ul li{
   width: 100%%;
   padding: 6%;
   background-color: #F04D44;
   color: #fff;
  }
  .menu ul li:hover{
   background-color: grey;
       color: red;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("html").on("contextmenu",function(e){
         //prevent default context menu for right click
         e.preventDefault();

         var menu = $(".menu"); 

         //hide menu if already shown
         menu.hide(); 
         
         //get x and y values of the click event
         var pageX = e.pageX;
         var pageY = e.pageY;

         //position menu div near mouse cliked area
         menu.css({top: pageY , left: pageX});

         var mwidth = menu.width();
         var mheight = menu.height();
         var screenWidth = $(window).width();
         var screenHeight = $(window).height();

         //if window is scrolled
         var scrTop = $(window).scrollTop();

         //if the menu is close to right edge of the window
         if(pageX+mwidth > screenWidth){
          menu.css({left:pageX-mwidth});
         }

         //if the menu is close to bottom edge of the window
         if(pageY+mheight > screenHeight+scrTop){
          menu.css({top:pageY-mheight});
         }

         //finally show the menu
         menu.show();
  }); 
  
  $("html").on("click", function(){
   $(".menu").hide();
  });
 });
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Menu div initially hidden -->
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/pages.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/dashboard.html">Main Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Mailing_List">Newsletter</a></li>
<li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Feedback_Survey">Feedback</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/Contact_Us">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
  
  
<!-- 
This code is developed by Anand Roshan for www.voidtricks.com  tutorial
Tutorial URI : http://www.voidtricks.com/custom-right-click-context-menu/
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <script>
 ;
 </script>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Custom Right Click Menu</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .menu{
   width: 300px;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 999999;
   display: none;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #713C3C;
  }
  .menu ul{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
  }
  .menu ul a{
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .menu ul li{
   width: 88%;
   padding: 6%;
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #fff;
  }
  .menu ul li:hover{
   background-color: grey;
       color: white;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("html").on("contextmenu",function(e){
         //prevent default context menu for right click
         e.preventDefault();

         var menu = $(".menu"); 

         //hide menu if already shown
         menu.hide(); 
         
         //get x and y values of the click event
         var pageX = e.pageX;
         var pageY = e.pageY;

         //position menu div near mouse cliked area
         menu.css({top: pageY , left: pageX});

         var mwidth = menu.width();
         var mheight = menu.height();
         var screenWidth = $(window).width();
         var screenHeight = $(window).height();

         //if window is scrolled
         var scrTop = $(window).scrollTop();

         //if the menu is close to right edge of the window
         if(pageX+mwidth > screenWidth){
          menu.css({left:pageX-mwidth});
         }

         //if the menu is close to bottom edge of the window
         if(pageY+mheight > screenHeight+scrTop){
          menu.css({top:pageY-mheight});
         }

         //finally show the menu
         menu.show();
  
  $("html").on("click", function(){
   $(".menu").hide();
  });
 });
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Menu div initially hidden -->
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
 
 </ul>
</div>


 </section>
  </div>  
  
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
   var accordionActive = false;
  
   $(window).on('resize', function() {
       var windowWidth = $(window).width();
       var $topMenu = $('#top-menu');
       var $sideMenu = $('#side-menu');     
       
       if (windowWidth < 768) {
          if ($topMenu.hasClass("active")) {             
            $topMenu.removeClass("active");
            $sideMenu.addClass("active");
            
            var $ddl = $('#top-menu .movable.dropdown');
            $ddl.detach();
            $ddl.removeClass('dropdown');
            $ddl.addClass('nav-header');
            
            $ddl.find('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('dropdown-toggle').addClass('link');
            $ddl.find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('dropdown-menu').addClass('submenu');
                        
            $ddl.prependTo($sideMenu.find('.accordion'));
            $('#top-menu #qform').detach().removeClass('navbar-form').prependTo($sideMenu);
            
            if (!accordionActive) {
               var Accordion2 = function(el, multiple) {
                 this.el = el || {};
                 this.multiple = multiple || false;

                  // Variables privadas
                 var links = this.el.find('.movable .link');
                 // Evento
                 links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown);
                }

              Accordion2.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
                var $el = e.data.el;
                $this = $(this),
                  $next = $this.next();

                $next.slideToggle();
                $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

                if (!e.data.multiple) {
                  $el.find('.movable .submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
                };
              }    

              var accordion = new Accordion2($('ul.accordion'), false); 
              accordionActive = true;
            }
          }
       }
       else {
          if ($sideMenu.hasClass("active")) {              
            $sideMenu.removeClass('active');
            $topMenu.addClass('active');
            
            var $ddl = $('#side-menu .movable.nav-header');
            $ddl.detach();
            $ddl.removeClass('nav-header');
            $ddl.addClass('dropdown');
            
            $ddl.find('.link').removeClass('link').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
            $ddl.find('.submenu').removeClass('submenu').addClass('dropdown-menu');
            
             $('#side-menu #qform').detach().addClass('navbar-form').appendTo($topMenu.find('.nav'));
            $ddl.appendTo($topMenu.find('.nav'));
          }
       }
   });
  
  /**/
  var $menulink = $('.side-menu-link'),       
      $wrap = $('.wrap');
  
  $menulink.click(function() {    
    $menulink.toggleClass('active');
    $wrap.toggleClass('active');    
    return false;
  });
  
  /*Accordion*/
  var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    // Variables privadas
    var links = this.el.find('.link');
    // Evento
    links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown);
  }

  Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
     var $el = e.data.el;
     $this = $(this),
      $next = $this.next();

    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

    if (!e.data.multiple) {
      $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
  } 

  var accordion = new Accordion($('ul.accordion'), false); 
  
  
});
 </script>
   
</body>
 

  
</html>


  </section>
 </div>
 
 <footer>
  <hr />
  
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 
 <!-- custom scrollbar plugin -->
 <script src="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
  (function($){
   $(window).on("load",function(){
    
    $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
     theme:"minimal"
    });
    
   });
  })(jQuery);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ reproduction... You've pasted the whole website here. Check out the [guide on creating a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I dont know what part is the error so yes i did without a choice, i had to remove some to to length restrictions!

Comment: If you start removing things little by little, you'll eventually arrive at a MVCE. It might just happen that you will figure out the error yourself while doing so, and learn a few things along the way. We're here to help, not do the work for you by going through the whole webpage.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is tagged with `php`.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue, the issue was a error `position absolute` in the css

Comment: It would be better if you could specify which `position: absolute` you had to change to fix your problem.  That will make the answer more useful to others who find this post and have a similar problem.

Comment: Validate your own answer and detail it a bit more if you can, so it can eventually help others.